# How can I package python+pygame programs as executables?

Tags: python, macos, windows-installer, pygame, py2exe

I used `py2exe` earlier for that but it doesn't seem to be maintained any more, the last package they have is for Python 2.6.

I need the application with Python 2.7 + Pygame.

Big bonus points if it lets me make OSX packages as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)? Last revision seems to have been made around 2 days ago, at the time of this writing, so it appears to be maintained, and claims to support Windows, Linux, and OSX.

[cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) also looks very promising. It also claims to be cross-platform. Yet another one is [py2app](https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/), which support OSX.

Comment: PyInstaller looked promising, but it crashed on both OSX and Windows, with two different exceptions, and I couldn't find any solutions to either online.

Comment: @taw: I added some other options to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed some bugs in PyInstaller and got it running under Windows. Now if only their bug tracker wasn't crashing and let me submit patches... Still no luck with PyInstaller on OSX, but that was a secondary target anyway. I'll check py2app at some later point.